# Generating names of pdf and txt files automatically

Tags: r

I am trying to run a for loop for a function and graph. I have different vectors (traits) i am running from the data. I want to run each traits through the for loop called i and output each result in a separate file with the corresponding trait name so i only have to run the command one time instead of 9 times. The file should be called ("bristleX trait 1.txt", "bristleX trait 2.txt",...,"bristleX trait i.txt") Also the same with the .pdf command as well. ("bristleX trait 1.pdf", "bristleX trait 2.pdf",...,"bristleX trait i.pdf")
I am having trouble with the sink and pdf functions; they will not output the same as regular titles or names with the paste() function. The functions using the i in traits just need the numbers 1 through 9 to work but can only do one at a time.

```
  library(qtl)
  data("bristleX")
    traits<-c(1:9)
    for(i in traits){
      sink(paste(file="bristleX trait",i".txt"))
      pdf(paste(file = "brixtleX trait",i".pdf", paper="special",width = 8.5, 
      height = 11, 
          family="Times", pointsize=11,bg="white",fg="black"))
      print("MR QTLs")

      out.mr <- scanone(bristleX, pheno.col=i, method="mr") # estimate LOD 
      #for a single phenotype
      summary(out.mr, threshold=3)
      plot(out.mr) # 

     sink()
     dev.off()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try your example, but as I can see you have an error here:

```
...
      sink(paste(file="bristleX trait",i".txt"))
      pdf(paste(file = "brixtleX trait",i".pdf", paper="special",width = 8.5, 
...
```

paste doesn't have file argument. You probably wanted:

```
...
      sink(file=paste("bristleX trait",i".txt"))
      pdf(file = paste("brixtleX trait",i".pdf", paper="special",width = 8.5, 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a mistake in you past function, you showl to use

```
paste("bristleXtrait",i,".txt")
```

instead of

```
paste("bristleXtrait",i".txt")
```

Also, you have to remplace the spaces in the file name. you could use the  `str_replace_all()` function

```
sink(file = str_replace_all(paste("bristleX trait",i,".txt"), pattern=" ", repl=""))
```